# Regular expression pattern to find a number within a semicolon delimited list of numbers

Tags: java, regex

```
String temp = "77"; // It can be 0 or 100 or any value

// So the pattern will be like this only but number can be change anytime
String inclusion = "100;0;77;200;....;90";
```

I need to write a regular expression so that I can see whether temp exists in inclusion or not so for that I wrote a regexPattern like this.

```
// This is the regular Expression I wrote.
String regexPattern = "(^|.*;)" + temp + "(;.*|$)";
```

So do you think this regular expression will work everytime or there is some problem with that regexPattern?

```
if(inclusion.matches(regexPattern)) {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run into issues if `temp` can contain special characters for regular expressions, but if it is always integers then your method should be fine.

However, a more straightforward way to do this would be to split your string on semi-colons and then see if `temp` is in the resulting array.

<strike>If you do stick with regex, you can simplify it a bit by dropping the `.*`, the following will work the same way as your current regex:</strike>

```
"(^|;)" + temp + "(;|$)"
```

**edit:** Oops, the above will actually not work, I am a bit unfamiliar with regex in Java and didn't realize that the entire string needs to match, thanks Affe!

Comment: That does *not* work as a drop in replacement to his existing code.  The see the javadco on `matches()`, it is tricksy.

Comment: I also wanted to know one more thing. Why some people are saying alternative of using regular expression. Is regex are not good to use in general?

Comment: @user1419563 - Regex is very well suited for certain things, but in general I think people find regular expressions hard to read and maintain, and feel that they should be avoided if there is a reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex:

```
temp = "77"
String searchPattern = ";" + temp + ";";
String inclusion = ";" + "100;0;77;200;....;90" + ";";
inclusion.indexOf(searchPattern);
```

Comment: what if temp is 7 and inclusion contains only 77 but not 7?

Comment: I also wanted to know one more thing. Why some people are saying alternative of using regular expression. Is regex are not good to use in general?

Comment: Regex is a very powerful tool, which I like and use a lot. But I've also learned from people smarter than me that it's often better to use the simplest tool that will get the job done. It's also a matter of personal preference. Use whichever you like :) For what it's worth, I would probably choose F.J.'s `split` approach.

Comment: Regex should be used when needed. In this case I think @alan is right and you don't really need to use regex. Regex involves more string processing than a search for a substring and it will be slower, more difficult to code and more exposed to potential bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative without regex

```
String inclusion2 = ";" + inclusion + ";";  // To ensure that all number are between semicolons
if (inclusion2.indexOf(";" + temp + ";") =! -1) {
   // found
}
```

Of course, no pattern recognition here (wildcards and the like)

Comment: That's why I add ";" before and after. Read more carefully.